# Show menu even if node it's not in that menu

Tags: theming, routes

Setup I got has two content types, page and article. Pages are normal pages and articles are news. On the site I also have three menus: main, sub and subsub. Main shows first level, sub shows second level items and subsub shows all below items.

Menu:

```
Front page
News
-Breaking news
About
-History
--Early years
-People in charge
Contact
```

Now when admin creates a news article it doesn't go to any menu. It's showed on the News page with view. And when user clicks the news it goes to the news article page where the news is showed fully. But now since the news article is not in menu, the submenu disappears. How can I "trink" Drupal to think that user is on sub page of News page -> The sub menu would visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few modules for this that you might be able to use: [Menu position](http://drupal.org/project/menu_position), [Menu Trails](http://drupal.org/project/menutrails) and [Menu Trail By Path](http://drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path). It's also possible to code the logic yourself with [menu_tree_set_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_set_path/7).

Comment: These looks good. I have to try it out. Though I'm using D7 so the other doesnt work.

Comment: You didn't mention which version of Drupal the site is built on so I just listed all the solid-looking modules for both versions that I could find. Glad that you got your problem resolved with one of them :)

Answer (score 0):

In the settings for the menu item itself, there is a checkbox below "enabled" that says "expanded". Check this box for all items whose children you want to be visible all the time.

Comment: No, I don't actually want the news articles to be in menu. Okey, I could add them to menu and then go and click then non-visible but this seems lot of work considering that we publish 10-20 news article per day. It would need to be somewow automated.

Comment: I think one of us is not understanding the other. It sounds like you want, for example, --Early Years and -History to show under About, even when you're not viewing History or Early Years or About. So you would click "Expanded" on the menu settings page for "About" and for "History". Then it doesn't matter where else on the site you are, you will be able to see them. Did I misunderstand your problem?